# What causes "Expecting value (near 1:1)" error? in algolia post request

Tags: python, json, algolia

i was was trying to post a request at algolia server , but was getting error

```
{
    "message": "Expecting value (near 1:1)",
    "status": 400
}
```

i tried reading all the doc and forum everybody suggested to change the

Content-Type to application/json, i tried that too but still i am getting the error

below is my code

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("spe6j23569-dsn.algolia.net")

payload = "%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22indexName%22%3A%22prod_ftd_products%22%2C%22params%22%3A%22analyticsTags=%5B%22plp%22%2C%22en-us%22%2C%22desktop%22%5D&clickAnalytics=true&clickAnalytics=true&clickAnalytics=true&facets=%5B%22*%22%5D&facets=%5B%22*%22%5D&facets=%5B%22*%22%5D&filters=collections.handle%3Aoccasion_birthday_flowers%20AND%20hasSeoUrl%3Atrue&filters=isAddon%3Afalse&getRankingInfo=true&getRankingInfo=true&getRankingInfo=true&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&maxValuesPerFacet=20&maxValuesPerFacet=20&maxValuesPerFacet=4&page=4&page=4&page=4&tagFilters=%22%7D%2C%7B%22indexName%22%3A%22prod_ftd_products_query_suggestions%22%2C%22params%22%3A%22analyticsTags&tagFilters=%22%7D%2C%7B%22indexName%22%3A%22prod_ftd_products%22%2C%22params%22%3A%22analyticsTags&tagFilters=%22%7D%5D%7D&=filters%3D&=query%3D&=query%3D&hitsPerPage=4&hitsPerPage=4"
decoded_payload = urllib.parse.unquote(payload)
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Referer': "https://www.ftd.com/",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Origin': "https://www.ftd.com",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': "empty",
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': "cors",
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': "cross-site"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.19.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.56.4)%3B%20react%20(18.2.0)%3B%20react-instantsearch%20(6.45.1)%3B%20react-instantsearch-hooks%20(6.45.1)%3B%20next.js%20(13.4.16)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.14.0)&x-algolia-api-key=c6b60ecfe0cea00169ae8fcc041ccb95&x-algolia-application-id=SPE6J23569", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data. Decode("utf-8"))
```

i tried changing the Content-Type to application/json and even tired application/json; charset=UTF-8 this but the same error was popping again and again

i was trying to get the json file

Comment: I recommend you use the `requests` module rather than `http.client`.

Comment: you may try to send it to https://httpbin.org/post and it should send back all what it gets from you - and you can see what you really send in request